# Build CSS file refused by Heroku app deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, react-router, parceljs

I have deployed a React + NodeJS app in Heroku and the deployment went well and worked for a few hours. However, after a cache deletion, it now refuses to load the page. The errors are the following ones:

`Refused to apply style from 'https://flix-reloaded.herokuapp.com/src.78399e21.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

and

`GET https://flix-reloaded.herokuapp.com/src.78399e21.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

The first one, the MIME error refers to a minified file produced by a Parcel build. It is called in a `index.html` file that lives inside the `dist` folder. This is the line calling it:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/src.78399e21.css">`

Its twin `.js` file is also called within `index.html`:
`<script src="/src.78399e21.js"></script>`

**Problem 1)**: I don' know what to do to make the CSS file accepted. within it, there are some comments imported from the SCSS original files related to each component. I tried both to remove the comments and add the `type` of the file as CSS but it hasn't worked. It should be a subtle detail, but I don't know what else to attempt.

**Problem 2:** The `JS` file that Heroku is not finding it is at the same folder of the `index.html`. However, the routing of the app has been defined to have `client` (`Router basename="/client"`) as root (https://flix-reloaded.herokuapp.com/client). If I manually type the URL with `client` (https://flix-reloaded.herokuapp.com/client/src.78399e21.css), the file is found, but changing the path to the file in the `index.html` (you can see below) solves the 404 problem, but brings another one (says that a "<" token is unexpected within a system js file that is out of bounds).

I tried to run another Parcel build, commiting changes, clean caches, but nothing worked. Can anyone provide me some help? I'll be happy to provide further details if necessary.

The `index.html` file code that lives inside the `dist` folder (where the production files live):

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>myFlix</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/src.78399e21.css"></head>

<body>
  <div class="app-container"></div>
  <script src="/src.78399e21.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I manually type the URL with client (https://flix-reloaded.herokuapp.com/client/src.78399e21.css), the file is found, but changing the path to the file in the index.html (you can see below) solves the 404 problem, but brings another one (says that a "<" token is unexpected within a system js file that is out of bounds).

This is because you need to make the same `/client/` fix to the `<script src="/src.78399e21.js"></script>` line.

In both cases, you've got the wrong URL for your CSS/JS files, and as a result the CSS/JS parsers are trying (and failing) to process the resulting 404 page's HTML as CSS/JS.

Comment: Thanks, @ceejavoz, it worked. I have manually written the path to both files. The css file was valid, the problem was just the path. However, I believe this is just a temporary fix, because I need to find out why the build that Parcel creates outputs that defective path inside `dist`. When I find the culprit, I will update this answer. But thanks in any case (you solved it).